# iOS : activityType doesn't work on UIactivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-share

hi this is my code I have implement UIactivityViewCotroller but when I click I don't see mail and Facebook app

```
@IBAction func activityView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = "This is some text that I want to share."
    let textToShare = [ text ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.mail ]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but I don't see those app 
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the function as follows

```
@IBAction func activityView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = "This is some text that I want to share."
    let textToShare = [ text ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop ]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Activity Controllers `excludedActivityTypes` means you are excluding those sharing options to list in `activityController`

Comment: thanks what exactly should I do?? I didn't understand completely

Comment: @Javad I have edited the answer. Replace the function with this code. If you add Facebook & mail in `excludedActivityType`, the activity will not list Facebook & mail

Comment: I don't see the mail and Facebook should I put any code or function

Comment: @Javad In your code, you have added a line `activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.mail ]` , Just replace that line with `activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop ]`

Comment: Did you checked it?

Comment: I Got I'm in simulator so I don't have twitter and Facebook app